# how to prevent cross bookings / Over- bookings in laravel booking code

Tags: mysql, laravel

I like to prevent the last-service double- or cross-bookings.
at the moment many users can check the availability (at the same time) for the same service, getting the availability and all can book the same service/ on the same date. which is a big problem and caused over-bookings.

any idea how to prevent this in Laravel?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You need a way to know how many users have booked for a particular service for a particular day

You also need to set a max number of bookings for each service for a day

Just before you save which user has booked a particular service, you can check if the service is fully booked, by checking the number of users that have already booked the service for that day if it is less than the max number of bookings and act accordingly

if you need more clarification or need help designing the database, ask